# Releasing memory by the resource

Tags: c#, .net

I have a program in c# which uses my local webcam, to capture and store images. I have buttons to click on start,stop,continue n etc.When I run the program it works properly for the first time after I turn my system on, but in the consecutive executions of the same thing I get an error (in pop-up window):

> An error occurred while capturing the video image. The video capture will now be terminated. Object reference not set to an instance of the object.

for which I assume that it might be because of the camera device, not releasing the memory it used. So how do I programatically free it up, when I click on the exit button? Below is part of the program and i get error in the webcam.start(0) method

namespace WinFormCharpWebCam
{

```
class WebCam
{

    private WebCamCapture webcam;
    private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox _FrameImage;
    private int FrameNumber = 30;
    public void InitializeWebCam(ref System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox ImageControl)
    {
        webcam = new WebCamCapture();
        webcam.FrameNumber = ((ulong)(0ul));
        webcam.TimeToCapture_milliseconds = FrameNumber;
        webcam.ImageCaptured += new WebCamCapture.WebCamEventHandler(webcam_ImageCaptured);
        _FrameImage = ImageControl;
    }

    void webcam_ImageCaptured(object source, WebcamEventArgs e)
    {
        _FrameImage.Image = e.WebCamImage;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        webcam.TimeToCapture_milliseconds = FrameNumber;
        webcam.Start(0); //error pops up when the execution comes to this method

    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        webcam.Stop();

    }

    public void Continue()
    {
        // change the capture time frame
        webcam.TimeToCapture_milliseconds = FrameNumber;

        // resume the video capture from the stop
        webcam.Start(this.webcam.FrameNumber);
    }

    public void ResolutionSetting()
    {
        webcam.Config();
    }

    public void AdvanceSetting()
    {
        webcam.Config2();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Read the [FAQ] and post some relevant code and information. Or reboot your computer before running the program.

Comment: Don't make assumptions about errors, debug them. Pinpoint the source of the exception by adding breakpoints and try..catch clauses.

Comment: I have added the code where I get the specified error.Try t help me out in this ! Thanks

Comment: @Codingactive, I have used same code and also i have same issue. Can you please describe more about how did you solve your porblem and put your complete code here if possible?

Answer (score 1):

You have a `NullReferenceException` thrown, not `OutOfMemoryException`.

Check your call stack to pinpoint where it originates. You can debug your app with debugger set to break on exception thrown, so it will break right where your exception occurs (press CRTL+D, E to open exceptions window in VS.NET).

Comment: The error originates when it has to start the webcam at "webcam.start(0)" method .

Answer (score 1):

From the error you are getting, I am guessing you downloaded the EasyWebCam Library.
If that is correct then here's how I worked around it:
1. I installed the Cyberlink's Youcam software on my machine.
2. Whenever I start my own application, the EasyWebCam library detects the Youcam WebSplitter on machine and prompts me to select either that or the default webcam driver.
3. I select the YouCam WebSplitter and the app works fine with it.


At this point, there comes along another snag: the Youcam process doesn't terminate when my application closes.
How I fixed it?
I had to get the Youcam process and Kill() it when my application window's about to exit.
This ugly solution worked.

Comment: You know any other easy solution for this problem ?

Comment: The EasyWebCam Library from Codeplex is not  open-source, so I can't think of any other way you can tweak the way it initializes the capture. However, you can download the original library from [here](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=1339&lngWId=10). Tweaking this original source should be a lot easier.